# lftp logging of removed source files

Tags: lftp

When I use --remove-source-files when pulling files from a remote server, there is no log of files being removed.

In theory, one could assume that as long as you're using --remove-source-files that they will be removed.  This is confusing because some of our jobs remove remote files and some don't.  Is there a way to have this indicated in the logs?  So far, I see that it is included in the debugging output to stderr.  I can parse that if I have to, but would prefer not to.

UPDATE FOR CLARITY:
I originally labeled this "rsync" when I meant "lftp".  They both have the same flag, so it was especially confusing to readers.

I'm looking for the remote removal to be logged to the logfile created when 'set xfer:log yes" is on.

The current lftp command I'm using is:

```
mirror --verbose=3 --Remove-source-files --no-perms \
  --no-empty-dirs --size-range=0-5368709120 \
  'sftp://fttestuser@localhost/path/to/files/' .
```

Comment: `rsync -v` enables verbose mode, which will list every file it handles.  If you use `--remove-source-files`, it _should_ try to remove any file it lists and will bark to stderr if it is unable to do so.

Comment: Ooops.  I meant "lftp" not "rsync".  Sorry.